# Reduction exercises for SAT solvers

Tags: computer-science, education, np-complete, satisfiability

I recently completed a course on [NP-Complete Problems](https://www.edx.org/course/np-complete-problems-uc-san-diegox-algs203x) at edX. The class introduced using SAT solvers, demonstrated using an SAT solver for [Sudoku](https://codingnest.com/modern-sat-solvers-fast-neat-underused-part-1-of-n/), and gave several exercises. The exercises were very difficult. I am not confident that I could reduce an arbitrary NP-complete problem to SAT.

I have looked for a book, talk, or website teaching you how to encode problems for a SAT solver. I have not found anything beginner-friendly. Can anyone point me to a learning resource? Ideally, I hope to find or purchase a series of guided exercises that start simple and gradually get complicated.

Comment: You might want to try asking on https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: CSTheory is for *research level* questions; it is definitely the wrong place to ask about basic polynomial transformations.

Comment: See [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/111703/114) on Computer Science Stack Exchange.  Condensed, you write a program that verifies a correct answer, convert that program to a circuit, then convert that circuit to CNF.  It works for any NP problem.

Comment: [A good collection of examples](https://yurichev.com/writings/SAT_SMT_by_example.pdf) that should keep you entertained for a while.

Comment: SAT/SMT by Example by Dennis Yurichev is precisely what I needed.